# What's the quickest way to get the mean of a set of numbers from the command line?

Tags: command-line, statistics, average, mean

Using any tools which you would expect to find on a nix system (in fact, if you want, msdos is also fine too), what is the easiest/fastest way to calculate the mean of a set of numbers, assuming you have them one per line in a stream or file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Awk

```
awk '{total += $1; count++ } END {print total/count}'
```

Answer (score 17):

```
awk ' { n += $1 }; END { print n / NR }'
```

This accumulates the sum in `n`, then divides by the number of items (`NR` = Number of Records).

Works for integers or reals.

Comment: Nice on the NR trick, wasn't sure which awk answer to accept so I copped out and went for the one with the most votes!

Answer (score 5):

Using [Num-Utils](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/) for UNIX:

```
average 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Interesting.  I installed this on Ubuntu and I had to specify the numbers on stdin, not as arguments.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -e 'while (<>) { $sum += $_; $count++ } print $sum / $count, "\n"';
```

Answer (score 2):

Using "st" (https://github.com/nferraz/st):

```
$ st numbers.txt
N      min   max    sum    mean  sd
10.00  1.00  10.00  55.00  5.50  3.03
```

Specify an option to see individual stats:

```
$ st numbers.txt --mean
5.5
```

(DISCLAIMER: I wrote this tool :))

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell, it would be

```
get-content .\meanNumbers.txt | measure-object -average
```

Of course, that's the verbose syntax.  If you typed it using aliases,

```
gc .\meanNumbers.txt | measure-object -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl.

```
@a = <STDIN>;

for($i = 0; $i < #@a; $i++)
{
   $sum += $a[i];
}

print $a[i]/#@a;
```

Caveat Emptor: My syntax may be a little whiffly.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby one liner

```
cat numbers.txt | ruby -ne 'BEGIN{$sum=0}; $sum=$sum+$_.to_f; END{puts $sum/$.}'
```

[source](http://blog.sam-we.com/docs/avgbash/)