# command line utility to print statistics of numbers in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, statistics

I often find myself with a file that has one number per line. I end up importing it in excel to view things like median, standard deviation and so forth.

Is there a command line utility in linux to do the same? I usually need to find the average, median, min, max and std deviation.

Comment: This is probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214363/whats-the-quickest-way-to-get-the-mean-of-a-set-of-numbers-from-the-command-lin.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24934/command-line-tool-to-calculate-basic-statistics-for-stream-of-values || http://serverfault.com/questions/548322/tool-to-do-statistics-in-the-linux-command-line

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-min-max-median-and-average-of-a-list-of-numbers-in

Comment: People coming for this question might also be interested in [`jp`, a CLI utility for making plots](https://github.com/sgreben/jp).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202889/44236

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is a breeze with R.  For a file that looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Use this:

```
R -q -e "x <- read.csv('nums.txt', header = F); summary(x); sd(x[ , 1])"
```

To get this:

```
       V1       
 Min.   : 1.00  
 1st Qu.: 3.25  
 Median : 5.50  
 Mean   : 5.50  
 3rd Qu.: 7.75  
 Max.   :10.00  
[1] 3.02765
```

- The `-q` flag squelches R's startup licensing and help output
- The `-e` flag tells R you'll be passing an expression from the terminal
- `x` is a `data.frame` - a table, basically.  It's a structure that accommodates multiple vectors/columns of data, which is a little peculiar if you're just reading in a single vector. This has an impact on which functions you can use.
- Some functions, like `summary()`, naturally accommodate `data.frames`. If `x` had multiple fields, `summary()` would provide the above descriptive stats for each.
- But `sd()` can only take one vector at a time, which is why I index `x` for that command (`x[ , 1]` returns the first column of `x`). You could use `apply(x, MARGIN = 2, FUN = sd)` to get the SDs for all columns.

Comment: Thanks. I have started using R since and I think it is a great tool to understand data

Comment: To save the extra search for how to get R on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install r-base`

Comment: R might be nice to use more in the future, but I'm guessing it's a huge library install, so I had thoughts about installing `st` form below.  Not related to that comment, but my `brew install R` just about an hour on a MacBook Pro Mid 2015 10.12.5 2.5GHz i7 16GB with Chrome, Atom, and other apps open.  Most of it was spent building some gcc jit patch with the Xcode CLT O_o, but now I am happily using parts of this answer :)

Comment: Here's a blog post on [general data-wrangling with bash tools](https://nickcanzoneri.com/bash/command-line/data/2018/03/20/data-analysis-first-aid.html) that might be of interest to people who found this question.

Answer (score 49):

Using "st" (https://github.com/nferraz/st)

```
$ st numbers.txt
N    min   max   sum   mean  stddev
10   1     10    55    5.5   3.02765
```

Or:

```
$ st numbers.txt --transpose
N      10
min    1
max    10
sum    55
mean   5.5
stddev 3.02765
```

(DISCLAIMER: I wrote this tool :))

Comment: Any info about installation for newbies

Comment: If you're using homebrew installing this is as simple as `brew install st`.

Comment: Beware that `st` may also reference to `simple terminal`.

Answer (score 40):

For the average, median & standard deviation you can use `awk`.  This will generally be faster than `R` solutions.  For instance the following will print the average :

```sh
awk '{a+=$1} END{print a/NR}' myfile
```

(`NR` is an `awk` variable for the number of records, `$1` means the first (space-separated) argument of the line (`$0` would be the whole line, which would also work here but in principle would be less secure, although for the computation it would probably just take the first argument anyway) and `END` means that the following commands will be executed after having processed the whole file (one could also have initialized `a` to `0` in a `BEGIN{a=0}` statement)).

Here is a simple `awk` script which provides more detailed statistics (takes a CSV file as input, otherwise change `FS`) :

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=",";
}
{
   a += $1;
   b[++i] = $1;
}
END {
    m = a/NR; # mean
    for (i in b)
    {
        d += (b[i]-m)^2;
        e += (b[i]-m)^3;
        f += (b[i]-m)^4;
    }
    va = d/NR; # variance
    sd = sqrt(va); # standard deviation
    sk = (e/NR)/sd^3; # skewness
    ku = (f/NR)/sd^4-3; # standardized kurtosis
    print "N,sum,mean,variance,std,SEM,skewness,kurtosis"
    print NR "," a "," m "," va "," sd "," sd/sqrt(NR) "," sk "," ku
}
```

It is straightforward to add min/max to this script, but it is as easy to pipe `sort` & `head`/`tail` :

```sh
sort -n myfile | head -n1
sort -n myfile | tail -n1
```

Answer (score 27):

Yet another tool which could be used for calculating statistics and view distribution in ASCII mode is **ministat**. It's a tool from FreeBSD, but it also packaged for popular Linux distribution like Debian/Ubuntu. Or you can simply download and build it from [sources](https://github.com/thorduri/ministat) - it only requires a C compiler and the C standard library.

Usage example:

```
$ cat test.log 
Handled 1000000 packets.Time elapsed: 7.575278
Handled 1000000 packets.Time elapsed: 7.569267
Handled 1000000 packets.Time elapsed: 7.540344
Handled 1000000 packets.Time elapsed: 7.547680
Handled 1000000 packets.Time elapsed: 7.692373
Handled 1000000 packets.Time elapsed: 7.390200
Handled 1000000 packets.Time elapsed: 7.391308
Handled 1000000 packets.Time elapsed: 7.388075

$ cat test.log| awk '{print $5}' | ministat -w 74
x <stdin>
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| x                                                                        |
|xx                                   xx    x x                           x|
|   |__________________________A_______M_________________|                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    N           Min           Max        Median           Avg        Stddev
x   8      7.388075      7.692373       7.54768     7.5118156    0.11126122
```

Answer (score 21):

Yep, it's called perl
and here is concise one-liner:

```
perl -e 'use List::Util qw(max min sum); @a=();while(<>){$sqsum+=$_*$_; push(@a,$_)}; $n=@a;$s=sum(@a);$a=$s/@a;$m=max(@a);$mm=min(@a);$std=sqrt($sqsum/$n-($s/$n)*($s/$n));$mid=int @a/2;@srtd=sort @a;if(@a%2){$med=$srtd[$mid];}else{$med=($srtd[$mid-1]+$srtd[$mid])/2;};print "records:$n\nsum:$s\navg:$a\nstd:$std\nmed:$med\max:$m\min:$mm";'
```

Example

```
$ cat tt
1
3
4
5
6.5
7.
2
3
4
```

And the command

```
cat tt | perl -e 'use List::Util qw(max min sum); @a=();while(<>){$sqsum+=$_*$_; push(@a,$_)}; $n=@a;$s=sum(@a);$a=$s/@a;$m=max(@a);$mm=min(@a);$std=sqrt($sqsum/$n-($s/$n)*($s/$n));$mid=int @a/2;@srtd=sort @a;if(@a%2){$med=$srtd[$mid];}else{$med=($srtd[$mid-1]+$srtd[$mid])/2;};print "records:$n\nsum:$s\navg:$a\nstd:$std\nmed:$med\max:$m\min:$mm";'
records:9
sum:35.5
avg:3.94444444444444
std:1.86256162380447
med:4
max:7.
min:1
```

Comment: I'm sure that works, but doing it all one line makes my eyes bleed.  Why not create a script, rather than that atrocity?

Comment: I'm from functional languages world (not M$, nor java), all people there speaks like that :) no one's hurt  (http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.263336.105)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "functional languages" != "write everything on one line as tersely as possible".

Comment: Are you open minded enough to make it == ??
sudoku solver in mentioned k language:
   p:+{(=x)x}'p,,3/:_(p:,/'+:\9#'!9)%3;f:{$[&/x;,x;,/f'@[x;i;:;]'&27=x[,/p i:x?0]?!10]}

Comment: Just because you *can* do something one line doesn't mean you *should.*

Comment: Oneliners are definitely not for reading. But they are great to just copy-paste into my putty, and get the stats on some numbers grepped out from apache log... So bua roxx

Comment: I just copied and pasted it into a terminal to get the info I needed. Much easier than writing it to a script just for one thing.

Comment: The command line (at least bash) supports multi-line strings, too. Just use a line break inside the literal.

Comment: "Programs are meant to be read by humans and only incidentally for computers to execute" - Donald Knuth.

Answer (score 18):

**Mean:**

```
awk '{sum += $1} END {print "mean = " sum/NR}' filename
```

**Median:**

```
gawk -v max=128 '

    function median(c,v,    j) { 
       asort(v,j) 
       if (c % 2) return j[(c+1)/2]
       else return (j[c/2+1]+j[c/2])/2.0
    }

    { 
       count++
       values[count]=$1
       if (count >= max) { 
         print  median(count,values); count=0
       } 
    } 

    END { 
       print  "median = " median(count,values)
    }
    ' filename
```

**Mode:**

```
awk '{c[$1]++} END {for (i in count) {if (c[i]>max) {max=i}} print "mode = " max}' filename
```

This mode calculation requires an even number of samples, but you see how it works...

**Standard Deviation:**

```
awk '{sum+=$1; sumsq+=$1*$1} END {print "stdev = " sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)**2)}' filename
```

Comment: Nicely done - and using a tool that is on every linux distro.

Comment: @rbellamy - thanks! And not just Linux - I administer FreeBSD systems, where the distinction between `awk` and `gawk` is important (since Plain Old Awk on BSD doesn't include `asort()`).

Comment: This is great.. I didn't have to install any additional tools!

Answer (score 18):

Yet another tool: https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/

```
# Example: calculate the sum and mean of values 1 to 10:
$ seq 10 | datamash sum 1 mean 1
55 5.5
```

Might be more commonly packaged (the first tool I found prepackaged for nix at least)

Answer (score 9):

Just in case, there's [`datastat`](https://sourceforge.net/p/datastat/code/), a simple program for Linux computing simple statistics from the command-line. For example,

```
cat file.dat | datastat
```

will output the average value across all rows for each column of file.dat. If you need to know the standard deviation, min, max, you can add the `--dev`, `--min` and `--max` options, respectively.

`datastat` has the possibility to aggregate rows based on the value of one or more "key" columns. For example,

```
cat file.dat | datastat -k 1
```

will produce, for each different value found on the first column (the "key"), the average of all other column values as aggregated among all rows with the same value on the key. You can use more columns as key fields (e.g., -k 1-3, -k 2,4 etc...).

It's written in C++, runs fast and with small memory occupation, and can be piped nicely with other tools such as `cut`, `grep`, `sed`, `sort`, `awk` etc.

Comment: Stylistic minor cringe for the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: Missing an authorship disclaimer, I think.

Answer (score 8):

[`data_hacks` is a Python command-line utility for basic statistics.](https://github.com/bitly/data_hacks)

The first example from that page produces the desired results:

```
$ cat /tmp/data | histogram.py
# NumSamples = 29; Max = 10.00; Min = 1.00
# Mean = 4.379310; Variance = 5.131986; SD = 2.265389
# each * represents a count of 1
    1.0000 -     1.9000 [     1]: *
    1.9000 -     2.8000 [     5]: *****
    2.8000 -     3.7000 [     8]: ********
    3.7000 -     4.6000 [     3]: ***
    4.6000 -     5.5000 [     4]: ****
    5.5000 -     6.4000 [     2]: **
    6.4000 -     7.3000 [     3]: ***
    7.3000 -     8.2000 [     1]: *
    8.2000 -     9.1000 [     1]: *
    9.1000 -    10.0000 [     1]: *
```

Answer (score 8):

You might also consider using [**clistats**](https://github.com/dpmcmlxxvi/clistats). It is a highly configurable command line interface tool to compute statistics for a stream of delimited input numbers.

#### I/O options

- Input data can be from a file, standard input, or a pipe
- Output can be written to a file, standard output, or a pipe
- Output uses headers that start with "#" to enable piping to gnuplot

#### Parsing options

- Signal, end-of-file, or blank line based detection to stop processing
- Comment and delimiter character can be set
- Columns can be filtered out from processing
- Rows can be filtered out from processing based on numeric constraint
- Rows can be filtered out from processing based on string constraint
- Initial header rows can be skipped
- Fixed number of rows can be processed
- Duplicate delimiters can be ignored
- Rows can be reshaped into columns
- Strictly enforce that only rows of the same size are processed
- A row containing column titles can be used to title output statistics

#### Statistics options

- Summary statistics (Count, Minimum, Mean, Maximum, Standard deviation)
- Covariance
- Correlation
- Least squares offset
- Least squares slope
- Histogram
- Raw data after filtering

NOTE: I'm the author.

Answer (score 8):

I found myself wanting to do this in a shell pipeline, and getting all the right arguments for R took a while. Here's what I came up with:

```sh
seq 10 | R --slave -e 'x <- scan(file="stdin",quiet=TRUE); summary(x)'
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00
```

The `--slave` option ["Make(s) R run as quietly as possible...It implies --quiet and --no-save."](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) The `-e` option tells R to treat the following string as R code. The first statement reads from standard in, and stores what's read in the variable called "x". The `quiet=TRUE` option to the [`scan`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/scan.html) function suppresses the writing of a line saying how many items were read. The second statement applies the [`summary`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/summary.html) function to `x`, which produces the output.

Answer (score 3):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# stdev - figure N, min, max, median, mode, mean, & std deviation
#
# pull out all the real numbers in the input
# stream and run standard calculations on them.
# they may be intermixed with other test, need
# not be on the same or different lines, and 
# can be in scientific notion (avagadro=6.02e23).
# they also admit a leading + or -.
#
# Tom Christiansen
# tchrist@perl.com

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw< min max >;

#
my $number_rx = qr{

  # leading sign, positive or negative
    (?: [+-] ? )

  # mantissa
    (?= [0123456789.] )
    (?: 
        # "N" or "N." or "N.N"
        (?:
            (?: [0123456789] +     )
            (?:
                (?: [.] )
                (?: [0123456789] * )
            ) ?
      |
        # ".N", no leading digits
            (?:
                (?: [.] )
                (?: [0123456789] + )
            ) 
        )
    )

  # abscissa
    (?:
        (?: [Ee] )
        (?:
            (?: [+-] ? )
            (?: [0123456789] + )
        )
        |
    )
}x;

my $n = 0;
my $sum = 0;
my @values = ();

my %seen = ();

while (<>) {
    while (/($number_rx)/g) {
        $n++;
        my $num = 0 + $1;  # 0+ is so numbers in alternate form count as same
        $sum += $num;
        push @values, $num;
        $seen{$num}++;
    } 
} 

die "no values" if $n == 0;

my $mean = $sum / $n;

my $sqsum = 0;
for (@values) {
    $sqsum += ( $_ ** 2 );
} 
$sqsum /= $n;
$sqsum -= ( $mean ** 2 );
my $stdev = sqrt($sqsum);

my $max_seen_count = max values %seen;
my @modes = grep { $seen{$_} == $max_seen_count } keys %seen;

my $mode = @modes == 1 
            ? $modes[0] 
            : "(" . join(", ", @modes) . ")";
$mode .= ' @ ' . $max_seen_count;

my $median;
my $mid = int @values/2;
if (@values % 2) {
    $median = $values[ $mid ];
} else {
    $median = ($values[$mid-1] + $values[$mid])/2;
} 

my $min = min @values;
my $max = max @values;

printf "n is %d, min is %g, max is %d\n", $n, $min, $max;
printf "mode is %s, median is %g, mean is %g, stdev is %g\n", 
    $mode, $median, $mean, $stdev;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also simple-r, which can do almost everything that R can, but with less keystrokes:

https://code.google.com/p/simple-r/

To calculate basic descriptive statistics, one would have to type one of:

```
r summary file.txt
r summary - < file.txt
cat file.txt | r summary -
```

For each of average, median, min, max and std deviation, the code would be:

```
seq 1 100 | r mean - 
seq 1 100 | r median -
seq 1 100 | r min -
seq 1 100 | r max -
seq 1 100 | r sd -
```

Doesn't get any simple-R!

Comment: Funny, it's a Perl wrapper to R. R is  not a programming language! >:-)

Answer (score 3):

Using [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv):

```
$ echo '3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5 9' |tr ' ' '\n' > numbers-one-per-line.csv

$ xsv stats -n < numbers-one-per-line.csv 
field,type,sum,min,max,min_length,max_length,mean,stddev
0,Integer,53,1,9,1,1,4.416666666666667,2.5644470922381863

# mode/median/cardinality not shown by default since it requires storing full file in memory:
$ xsv stats -n --everything < numbers-one-per-line.csv | xsv table
field  type     sum  min  max  min_length  max_length  mean               stddev              median  mode  cardinality
0      Integer  53   1    9    1           1           4.416666666666667  2.5644470922381863  4.5     5     7
```

Comment: Installing this with `brew` revealed lots of dependencies. Pretty "heavy" for this functionality.

Comment: So don't use brew? https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv/releases has precompiled binaries for macos, so there should be no reason to install the full rust toolchain or whatever it is brew does.

Answer (score 2):

Another tool: [tsv-summarize](https://ebay.github.io/tsv-utils/docs/tool_reference/tsv-summarize.html), from [eBay's tsv utilities](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils). Min, max, mean, median, standard deviation are all supported. Intended for large data sets. Example:

```
$ seq 10 | tsv-summarize --min 1 --max 1 --median 1 --stdev 1
1    10    5.5    3.0276503541
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 2):

Also, the self-write [stats](https://github.com/hjmangalam/scut), (bundled with 'scut') a perl util to do just that. Fed a stream of numbers on STDIN, it tries to reject non-numbers and emits the following:

```
$ ls -lR | scut -f=4 | stats
Sum       3.10271e+07
Number    452
Mean      68643.9
Median    4469.5
Mode      4096
NModes    6
Min       2
Max       1.01171e+07
Range     1.01171e+07
Variance  3.03828e+11
Std_Dev   551206
SEM       25926.6
95% Conf  17827.9 to 119460
          (for a normal distribution - see skew)
Skew      15.4631
          (skew = 0 for a symmetric dist)
Std_Skew  134.212
Kurtosis  258.477
          (K=3 for a normal dist)
```

It can also do a number of transforms on the input stream and emit only the unadorned value if you ask it;  ie 'stats --mean' will return the mean as an unlabelled float.

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer uses R. Using the same tool, I find a script nicer to work with (than a one-liner) as it can be modified more comfortably to add any specific stats, or format the output differently.

Given this file `data.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Having this `basic-stats` script in `$PATH`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

# Build a numeric vector.
x <- as.numeric(readLines("stdin"))

# Custom basic statistics.
basic_stats <- data.frame(
    N = length(x), min = min(x), mean = mean(x), median = median(x), stddev = sd(x),
    percentile_95 = quantile(x, c(.95)), percentile_99 = quantile(x, c(.99)),
    max = max(x))

# Print output.
print(round(basic_stats, 3), row.names = FALSE, right = FALSE)
```

Execute `basic-stats < data.txt` to print to stdout the following:

```
 N  min mean median stddev percentile_95 percentile_99 max
 10 1   5.5  5.5    3.028  9.55          9.91          10
```

The formatting can look a bit nicer by replacing the last 2 lines of the script with the following:

```
# Print output. Tabular formatting is done by the `column` command.
temp_file <- tempfile("basic_stats_", fileext = ".csv")
write.csv(round(basic_stats, 3), file = temp_file, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
system(paste("column -s, -t", temp_file))
. <- file.remove(temp_file)
```

This is the output now, with 2 spaces between columns (instead of 1 space):

```
N   min  mean  median  stddev  percentile_95  percentile_99  max
10  1    5.5   5.5     3.028   9.55           9.91           10
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough solutions ?-) : I would like to toss in gnuplot stats command.
Gnuplot is a remarkably fast data analytics tool - plotting, regression...

```
seq 10 | gnuplot -e "stats '-' u 1"

* FILE: 
  Records:           10
  Out of range:       0
  Invalid:            0
  Header records:     0
  Blank:              0
  Data Blocks:        1

* COLUMN: 
  Mean:               5.5000
  Std Dev:            2.8723
  Sample StdDev:      3.0277
  Skewness:           0.0000
  Kurtosis:           1.7758
  Avg Dev:            2.5000
  Sum:               55.0000
  Sum Sq.:          385.0000

  Mean Err.:          0.9083
  Std Dev Err.:       0.6423
  Skewness Err.:      0.7746
  Kurtosis Err.:      1.5492

  Minimum:            1.0000 [ 0]
  Maximum:           10.0000 [ 9]
  Quartile:           3.0000 
  Median:             5.5000 
  Quartile:           8.0000
```