# How can i summarize by group in R?

Tags: r

I'm using summary to get stats for a number list:

```
read.csv('nums.txt', header = F)
summary(x)
```

nums.txt:

```
value
1
2
3
```

How do i summarize this data by group/category using summary function?

nums.txt

```
category,value
A,1
A,2
A,3
B,4
B,5
B,6
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What have you searched for?  This question has been answered many times on SO.

Comment: The answer is in your question: `by()`

Comment: Also look for `tapply` here on SO.

Comment: I'm new to R and i'm trying to extend this command line oneliner to use group by: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9826464/51402

Answer (score 1):

If I google "r summary by"  the first answer that comes up for me is a link to http://www.statmethods.net/stats/descriptives.html
Which has a solution to your problem.

Another solution not mentioned there is as follows

```
 library(data.table)
 x <- data.table(x)

 x[, summary(Value), by=list(Group1, Group2)]   # assuming more than one group. Otherwise, just use by=Group1
```