# Bash - Find variable in many .txt files and calculate statistics

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, statistics

I have many .txt files in a folder. They are full of statistics, and have a name that's representative of the experiment those statistics are about.

```
exp_1_try_1.txt
exp_1_try_2.txt
exp_1_try_3.txt

exp_2_try_1.txt
exp_2_try_2.txt

exp_other.txt
```

In those files, I need to find the value of a variable with a specific name, and use them to calculate some statistics: min, max, avg, std dev and median.

The variable is a decimal value and dot "." is used as a decimal separator. No scientific notation, although it would be nice to handle that as well.

```
#in file exp_1_try_1.txt
var1=30.523
var2=0.6

#in file exp_1_try_2.txt
var1=78.98
var2=0.4

#in file exp_1_try_3.txt
var1=78.100
var2=1.1
```

In order to do this, I'm using bash. Here's an old script I made before my bash skills got rusty. It calculates the average of an integer value.

```
#!/bin/bash

folder=$1
varName="nHops"

cd "$folder"
grep -r -n -i --include="*_out.txt" "$varName" . | sed -E 's/(.+'"$varName"'=([0-9]+))|.*/\2/' | awk '{count1+=$1; count2+=$1+1}END{print "avg hops:",count1/NR; print "avg path length:",count2/NR}' RS="\n"
```

I'd like to modify this script to:

- support finding decimal values of variable length
- calculate more statistics

In particular std dev and median may require special attention.

**Update**: Here's my try to solve the problem using only UNIX tools, partially inspired [by this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13779). It works fine, except it does not calculate the standard deviation. The chosen answer uses Perl and is probably much faster.

```
#!/bin/bash

folder=$1
varName="var1"

cd "$folder"
grep -r -n -i --include="exp_1_run_*" "$varName" . | sed -E 's/(.+'"$varName"'=([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?))/\2/' | sort -n | awk '
  BEGIN {
    count = 0;
    sum = 0;
  }
  {
    a[count++] = $1;
    sum += $1;
  }
  END {
    avg = sum / count;
    if( (count % 2) == 1 ) {
      median = a[ int(count/2) ];
    } else {
      median = ( a[count/2] + a[count/2-1] ) / 2;
    }
    OFS="\t";
    OFMT="%.6f";
    print avg, median, a[0], a[count-1];
  }
'
```

Comment: Don't have time to offer a more complete answer, but I think you'll find some useful pointers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9789806/143319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract just the values, use the `-o` and `-P` grep options:

```
grep -rioPh --include="*_out.txt" "(?<=${varName}=)[\d.]+" .
```

That looks for a pattern like `nHops=1.234` and just prints out `1.234`

Given your sample data:

```
$ var="var1"
$ grep -oPh "(?<=$var=)[\d.]+" exp_1_try_{1,2,3}.txt 
30.523
78.98
78.100
```

To output some stats, you should be able to pipe those numbers into your favourite stats program. Here's an example:

```
grep -oPh "(?<=$var=)[\d.]+" f? | 
perl -MStatistics::Basic=:all -le '
    @data = <>; 
    print "mean: ", mean(@data);
    print "median: ", median(@data);
    print "stddev: ", stddev(@data)
'
```

```
mean: 62.53
median: 78.1
stddev: 22.64
```

---

Of course, since this is perl, we don't need grep or sed at all:

```
perl -MStatistics::Basic=:all -MList::Util=min,max -lne '
        /'"$var"'\s*=\s*(\d+\.?\d*)/ and push @data, $1
    } END {
        print "mean: ", mean(@data);
        print "median: ", median(@data);
        print "stddev: ", stddev(@data);
        print "min: ", min(@data);
        print "max: ", max(@data);
' exp_1_try_*
```

```
mean: 62.53
median: 78.1
stddev: 22.64
min: 30.523
max: 78.98
```

Comment: I tried to make a pattern for an arbitrary number of spaces around the equals, but I get the error "lookbehind assertion is not fixed length. Here's my code `grep -rioPh --include="exp_1_run_*" "(?<=${varName}\s*=\s*\K)[\d]+\.?[\d]*`

Comment: If you use `\K`, you don't need the look-behind.  `grep ... "${varName}\s*=\s*\K[\d]+\.?[\d]*"` -- may have to double the backslashes in double quotes

Comment: You can do away with sed and grep altogether

Comment: I used sprintf to round the number to a specific precision before printing it. Here's the trick `print "mean: ", sprintf("mean: %.6f", mean(@data))`